# Mapping Multiple SQL SELECTs to a single Keyless Entity Framework Core entity

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am dealing with creating billings that uses a fairly massive amount of data (2+ million records overall), so I was forced to use some direct `SQL` to speed up the data loading as using pure `EF` was too slow.

Using this entity:

```
[Keyless]
public class BillingAggregate
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public List<Debt> Debts { get; set; }

    public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }

    public List<Credit> Credits { get; set; }
}
```

Added to the `DataContext` as:

```
public DbSet<BillingAggregate> BillingAggregate { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BillingAggregate>().ToSqlQuery("EXEC [dto].[GetForMonthlyBilling]");
}
```

With my `Stored Procedure` as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetForMonthlyBilling]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #TempCustomerIDsForBilling([CustomerId] bigint)

    INSERT INTO #TempCustomerIDsForBilling([CustomerId]) 
        SELECT DISTINCT [CustomerId]
            FROM [dbo].[Debt] debt
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[DebtType] debtType ON debt.[DebtTypeId] = debtType.[DebtTypeId]
            WHERE debtType.[IsCollectible] = 1

    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Customer] WHERE [CustomerId] IN (SELECT [CustomerId] FROM #TempCustomerIDsForBilling)

    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Debt] WHERE [CustomerId] IN (SELECT [CustomerId] FROM #TempCustomerIDsForBilling)

    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Payment] WHERE [CustomerId] IN (SELECT [CustomerId] FROM #TempCustomerIDsForBilling)

    SELECT * 
        FROM [dbo].[Credit] credit
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Debt] debt ON credit.[DebtId] = debt.[DebtId]
        WHERE [CustomerId] IN (SELECT [CustomerId] FROM #TempCustomerIDsForBilling)

    DROP TABLE #TempCustomerIDsForBilling
END
GO
```

This seems to be all that the documentation that I was able to find requires me to do... however, when I do a standard query:

```
var billingAggregate = await dbContext.BillingAggregate.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

It immediately throws the error:

```
{"Sequence contains no elements"}
```

The immediacy of the error makes me think that the `Stored Procedure` fails to even run, as running it in SQL alone takes 40+ seconds... what am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8127

Answer (score 0):

For whomever this may help, as per `Svyatoslav Danyliv`'s link, it seems this is currently not possible with `EF Core` (though, was possible with `EF 6`). As a workaround, I had to drop down to a lower lever API that `EF Core` uses. I created it as an `Extension Method` so that I never have to see this "garbage" again :)

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static async Task<List<BillingHelper>> GetBillingsAsync(this MyDataContext dbContext)
    {
        var customers = new List<Customer>();
        var customerAddresses = new List<CustomerAddress>();
        var debts = new List<Debt>();
        var payments = new List<Payment>();
        var credits = new List<Credit>();
        
        using (var command = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetForMonthlyBilling]";
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (command.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                command.Connection.Open();

            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
                {
                    var customerType = typeof(Customer);
                    var customerProperties = customerType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                    var customerDictionary = customerProperties.ToDictionary(property => property.Name.ToUpper(), property => property);

                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        var customer = new Customer();

                        for (int index = 0; index < reader.FieldCount; index++)
                        {
                            var currentColumnName = reader.GetName(index).ToUpper();
                            if (customerDictionary.ContainsKey(currentColumnName))
                            {
                                var property = customerDictionary[currentColumnName];
                                if ((property != null) && property.CanWrite)
                                {
                                    var value = reader.GetValue(index);
                                    property.SetValue(claimant, (value == DBNull.Value ? null : value), null);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        customers.Add(claimant);
                    }

                    // This loads the next "SELECT", that is Result Set
                    await reader.NextResultAsync();

                    var customerAddressType = typeof(CustomerAddress);
                    // ... similar as above for Customer

                    await reader.NextResultAsync();

                    var debtType = typeof(Debt);
                    // ... similar as above for Customer
                    
                    await reader.NextResultAsync();

                    // ...
                }
            }
        }

        // From here to the end of this method takes C# compiler a long time to do
        // opportunity for optimization perhaps.
        var billings = customers.Select(customer => new BillingHelper 
        {
            CustomerId = customer.CustomerId,
            Customer = customer,
            Debts = debts.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId).ToList(),
            Payments = payments.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId).ToList()
        }).ToList();

        foreach (var billing in billings)
        {
            var debtIds = billing.Debts.Select(x => x.DebtId);

            billing.Credits = credits.Where(x => debtIds.Contains(x.DebtId)).ToList();

            billing.Customer.Addresses = customerAddresses.Where(x => x.CustomerId == billing.CustomerId).ToList();
        }

        return billings;
    }
}
```